# Can I import data from an Excel .iqy file to a sharepoint list?

Tags: list, excel

Can I import an .iqy file into SharePoint 2010 list? Help, please.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot import an iqy file. It just defines the query for Excel. The only way would be to import the data in excel using the web query and then import (the imported) data from the sheet into the list.
Another approach would be to use Excel Services but I think you need to enable the external datasources then (not sure).